# Why Eclipse CDT (linux version) cannot locate the UCHAR I defined?

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I am using `Eclipse 3.8.1 CDT` on `Xubuntu 15.04 i386`.

In the following screenshot, I have included the necessary `../Common/Common.h` file, which has `typedef u_char UCHAR`. But why the UCHAR still cannot be resolved?

[image]

### ADD 1

Below is the full content of `Common.h`.

[image]

And the error:

[image]

### ADD 2  - Issue seems to be solved, though not sure why.

I followed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8np8i.png) to import the project as a `Makefile` project. It can compile now.

[image]

So it seems there's some difference between the following 2 ways to create a C project.

1. New C Project -> Executable -> Empty Project -> (then import source 
   code)   -- cannot compile
2. New C Project -> Makefile project -> Empty Project -> (then specify 
   source code) -- can compile

### ADD 3

Seems the root cause is as below. I need to uncheck the `Generate Makefiles automatically`. And remove the `Debug` suffix from the Build directory. This way, project type 1 above can compile, too.

So what's learned is:

- **Understand what's going on behind the scene when you click the `Build project` menu.**
- **And ensure the right Makefile is used.**

[image]

Comment: Have you built? The Eclipse indexer doesn't run unless you actually build.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I built. It failed due to this unknown type name `UCHAR`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just add the errors.

Comment: So, let's read it together. unknown type `UCHAR` in the file `Common.h`. Not in `main`. So, `Common.h` does not include the definition of that type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The `Common.h` contains the typedef for `UCHAR`. `main` also has similar errors. I edited my screenshot to highlight the `typedef u_char UCHAR`.

Comment: Ah, wait, sorry.. got confused a bit..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Take your time.

Comment: Interesting. Can you expand the enum definitions as well?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Expanded. I updated the image.

Comment: How about `u_char`, whwre is it defined?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is defined in `types.h`, which is a system header file located in the Linux system include folder.

Comment: It is. But it is not (explicitly) included by your files.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes indeed. Let me try adding it.\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88721/discussion-between-smwikipedia-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the root cause is as below. I need to uncheck the `Generate Makefiles automatically`. And remove the `Debug` suffix from the Build directory. This way, project type 1 above can compile, too.

So what's learned is:

- **Understand what's going on behind the scene when you click the `Build project` menu.**
- **And ensure the right Makefile is used.**

[image]